# Json append results in error of - "No operator matches the given name and argument types"

Tags: postgresql, json

```
clusters_v2=# UPDATE cluster SET "clusterCALogs" = "clusterCALogs" || '["test"]'::jsonb WHERE "clusterId" = 9;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json || jsonb
LINE 1: ...ATE cluster SET "clusterCALogs" = "clusterCALogs" || '["test...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233548/1663462 I should be able to append to the JSON array? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My column type for `"clusterCALogs"` was `json`... It had to be `jsonb`.

Comment: You should probably change the type of the column, but if you don't you can still  dynamically cast the data `set "clusterCALogs" = "clusterCALogs"::jsonb  || '["test"]'::jsonb`